# Swift runtime error (exc_bad_access) AVAudioRecorder, recordSettings

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I have been struggling to change a piece of code for recording audio from swift 1.2 to swift 2. With the help of people here, I made some changes and eventually got rid of all the compiler errors. But now, after I run the code, login into Twitter, and then click on the Record button in the simulator, it crashes and gives me a runtime error. Please see the picture here:

[image: error]

Also, I'm not sure if this is important or not, but I removed "AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless))" from the code and commented out "self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true" and "self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()" from the code, and it wasn't crashing anymore, but obviously that's not how the code is supposed to run at the very end...

Here is the full version of code. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks a lot for your help

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {


    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    self.audioURL = "sound.m4a"
    var pathComponents = [baseString, self.audioURL]
    var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)
    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch (_) {
    }
//        session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

//        var recordSettings: [String : AnyObject] = Dictionary()
//        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
//        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
//        recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
//        recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

    let recordSettings = [
        AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
        AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless)),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue)),
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(320000))
    ]

//        self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL, settings: recordSettings, error: nil)
    self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder()
    print("aaaaa")
    do {
        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL!, settings: recordSettings)

    } catch (_) {

    }
    self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()


    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
//    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
//        super.init(coder : aDecoder)
//        self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder()
//    }

@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder
var audioURL = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.saveButton.enabled = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func recordTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.playButton.enabled = true
}

@IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

Comment: 1- Do not force-unwrap `audioNSURL`, use `if let` before to guarantee it's not nil. 2- Do not ignore the errors in the `catch` blocks. // It should be enough already to fix your problems -- or to be able to debug them properly.

Answer (score 1):

I see one forcefully unwrapped optional. Replace your error handling with the following

```
if let url = audioNSURL {
        self.audioRecorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(URL: url, settings: recordSettings)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both Eric and Lukas. I did some further trimming to my whole code and after all I guess I made  it work. Now, it compiles without error and also it doesn't do a runtime crash. I'm just posting the final version of my working code so that if anyone else was facing similar issues they can use it.

Thanks again and best to all the awesome guys who contribute here on Stackoverflow.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder?

@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.saveButton.enabled = false
}

func setRecorder() {

    do {
        let baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first!
        let pathComponents = [baseString, "music.m4a"]
        let audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
        try session.setActive(true)

        var recordSettings = [String : AnyObject]()
        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
        recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
        recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL!, settings: recordSettings)
        self.audioRecorder!.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder!.prepareToRecord()
    } catch (_) {
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func recordTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.playButton.enabled = true
}

@IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

Comment: This code is not working for swift 3.0 when I exported it to swift 3.0.